# Set background color for customview?

Tags: android, canvas, setbackground

I have a custom view and I have to set background color for it every two seconds.I can use `canvas.drawARGB()` or `view.setBackgroundColor()`.Both change color but I need to increase performance,because that change repeats every two seconds.So I want to know which way is faster?canvas.drawARGB() or view.setBackgroundColor()?

Comment: both methods are the same when it comes to speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `traceview` tool if you really have to actually see what works faster.